# Google Places Autocomplete: rectangular bounds vs radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

We are using the Javascript API v3 and I want to add a radius to get more local results. But I can't get it to work.

The docs say to use radius with the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) but use a rectangular LatLngBounds for the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete). Is that right or can I use radius with Javascript API?

Doesn't work:

```
    var defaultPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(28.522399, -81.415558);

    var optionsAuto = {
        location: defaultPlace,
        radius: 20000
    };

    var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2, optionsAuto);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use radius with the Javascript API.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions

The Javascript API is different from the REST API.  I suppose if you really needed the radius, you could proxy the result of the REST call into your application.  But it shouldn't be too difficult to create some method that translates a radius value into a square bounding box for use in the Javascript API.